# How to programmatically find the version of a loaded shared library?

Tags: c++, c, linux, shared-libraries

I know I can get the version of some linux shared libraries just by running it.  e.g.

`bash$ /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6`

`GNU C Library (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.23-0ubuntu9) stable release version 2.23, by Roland McGrath et al.`

I also can get the loaded shared libraries programmatically in a running process using [dl_iterate_phdr(3)](https://linux.die.net/man/3/dl_iterate_phdr).

How can I get the version information programmatically?

Comment: Your trick of running it only works for libc.  You could look at the package version using rpm or dpkg.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58846/viewing-linux-library-executable-version-info

Basically, ELF contains field SONAME which tells the library name with the major version.